# Why isn't it cow meat prohibited when it is said to cause sickness?

Tags: hadith, fiqh, food

I've come across to the following hadith:

> عليكم بألبان البقر و سمنانها ، و إياكم و لحومها ، **فإن ألبانها و سمنانها دواء و شفاء ، و لحومها داء**
>   ... The milk of the cow contains healing, its fat is a medicine, **and beware (iyyakum) of its meat, which causes sickness.**.

Which may be found in [this video quoted by Hamza Yusuf](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tuSOld4TTwM), in Suyutis book [Aljami' As-saghir](http://www.tchalabi.com/doc/mukhtasr_sahih_jama_sagher.pdf), by Tabarani as well as Al-Bayhaqi and it also was declared as sahih by Albani.

---

While this hadith often is used as a default understanding that everything that causes harm is forbidden:

> There should be neither harming (darar) nor reciprocating harm (dirar).
>   [Link](https://sunnah.com/nawawi40/32)

This hadith or this understanding is for instance [prohibiting smoking](https://islamqa.info/en/10922) and other things that may or do cause harm. If the case is that everything that do cause harm is prohibited, and this hadith about cow meat causing sickness, **wouldn't the same conclusion be drawn, that eating cow meat is prohibited?**

Comment: Red meat is very nutritious and contains many vitamins, antioxidants etc. However eating too much of it is bad for you. So I would suggest that if you do eat red meat, eat it in moderation. The Prophet Muhammad (peace be upon him) said: "Do good deeds properly, sincerely and moderately. . .Always adopt a middle, moderate, regular course, whereby you will reach your target (of paradise)." I'm not exactly sure the number of times a week that is considered to be in moderation, but one would assume the limit to be where it is considered to be unhealthy.

Comment: Thanks for your comment but that isn't actually relevant to my question itself.

Comment: Cow meat is a type of red meat.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sheikh Riyad al-Musaymiri, professor at Al-Imam University in Riyadh commented on this issue thus:

> In accordance with the general principles of Islamic Law, beef is
>   essentially lawful. Allah says: “It is He who created for you all that
>   is in the Earth.” [[Surah al-Baqarah: 29](https://quran.com/2/29)]
>
> Allah also says: “It is He who has put forth the Earth for His
>   creatures.” [[Surah al-Rahman: 10]](https://quran.com/55/10)
>
> This hadith, which is used as evidence to support the opinion that
>   beef consumption is disliked, is of disputed authenticity among
>   scholars. **The stronger view is that it is unauthentic**.
>
> This view is supported by the hadith related by Jabir that the Prophet
>   (peace be upon him) slaughtered a cow on `A’ishah’s behalf on the Day
>   of Sacrifice. [[Sahih Muslim (1319)]](https://www.sunnah.com/urn/230300)
>
> It is also supported by the fact that `A’ishah said: “The Prophet
>   (peace be upon him) sacrificed cows on behalf of his wives.” [[Sahîh
>   al-Bukhârî (5559)](https://sunnah.com/bukhari/73/15)]
>
> From this, it would seem apparent that, in Islamic Law, beef
>   consumption is not disliked.

Shaykh Al Albani who declared this hadith as saheeh said:

> Yes, it has been authenticated from the Prophet صلى الله عليه وسلم
>   during his farewell pilgrimage, that he sacrificed a cow for his
>   wives. And it has also been authenticated that he صلى الله عليه وآله
>   وسلم ordered us with the fat of the cow and prohibited us from its
>   meat, because its fat is a cure and its meat is a disease.
>
> The scholars have reconciled between this hadith and the hadith of his
>   sacrificing the cow for his wives, by stating the intention behind the
>   prohibition of cow’s meat is only referring to **consuming large
>   quantities of it**. As for eating it sometimes; there is no problem or
>   any harm in this. And it is without any doubt permissible; because the
>   intent behind the prohibition of beef is to consume large quantities
>   of it; and to use beef as a replacement for the meat of sheep, goats
>   and camels. This is the answer of the scholars.

Also; Ibn Qayyim wrote in 'Tibb An-Nabawi':

> "Cow meat is cold and dry, heavy on the stomach and produces black,
>   bilious blood that is only suitable for hard workers. **Eating cow meat
>   excessively** for those who are not used to it causes black bilious
>   illnesses. The harm that this meat causes will be neutralised when
>   one eats it with spices, garlic, ginger and cinnamon. The meat of
>   fat calves is one of the best, mildest and tastiest types of food. It
>   is warm and wet and if fully digested, it provides good nutrition."

As for you comparing smoking to cow meat which may be harmful if consumed in large quantities, this is an invalid argument, because these foods are permissible and beneficial in principle, and are only harmful in certain cases, such as if one consumes too much of them. But smoking will always be harmful for your health and it will harm people around you.

Shaykh al-Islam (may Allah have mercy on him) said:

> If he fears that it will harm him, then it becomes haram for him to
>   eat it. It is not permissible for
>   a person to eat that which will harm him or to wear that which will
>   harm him or to sit on that which will harm him. Even the Sahaabah (may
>   Allah be pleased with them), with regard to prostration, if the heat
>   would harm them, they would spread out their garments and prostrate on
>   them, lest they be harmed and so that they might be at ease in prayer.

What Shaykh al-Islam mentioned comes under the heading of fear of harm and indigestion, meaning that it is not as a result of the food itself, rather it is the result of consuming too much of it.

Comment: I like your references! But in my opinion its not relevant **to my question** if the hadith is sahih or not. But I am looking for a more detailed explanation of my questions, which isn't discussed in the quotes.

Comment: Didn't you want the opinion of scholars regarding the prohibition of cow meat?

Comment: Ok I have edited my answer. Hope it helps more now

Comment: +1 Great. Smoking was just an example. You could change it to **sugar**, who according to most scientists harms the health.

Comment: I think smoking fits better lol

Comment: Well everyone prohibit smoking, but no one prohibits **sugar** so I think commenting on why sugar is not prohibited, while sugar too is [pretty harmful](http://www.health.harvard.edu/blog/eating-too-much-added-sugar-increases-the-risk-of-dying-with-heart-disease-201402067021)? Also if you could draw an conclusion on my last question, that would be great: *"Now, if it isn't prohibited due to reasons as "it only causes harm if you eat it often", would this mean that if we eat it a lot, like 3 - 4 times a week mean, it is prohibited? "* Eating more than 500g per week is said to be harmful.

Comment: I made some edits in my question to simplify it and make it less broad. But the last question is still the same, if you could answer it, i will then accept your answer: **"If it isn't prohibited (to eat cow meat) due to reasons as "it only causes harm if you eat it often", would this mean that if we eat it a lot, like 4 times a week mean, it is prohibited?"**

Comment: @Kilise I think it depends on the reason of its prohibition. If it wont cause you harm if you eat it alot then yeah you can eat alot.

Comment: Yeah I understand that, but you won't know it has harmed you before it is to late. Anyway, in order to make this less broad i will edit my question, accept your answer and ask another.

Comment: Yeah ask another question. I am a little bit confused.

Answer (score 3):

First of all we should check:
**does the qur'an prohibit eating cow meat?**

**No** (read for example [6:142-147](http://legacy.quran.com/6/142-147)), where Allah **allowed eating all livestock**, but showed why some of that was partly prohibitted for jews!

Of course there's one restriction which is also a general rule from the qur'an: we shouldn't eat in excess, and always try to find and follow the middle way!

Also note that if this hadith was sahih? Why did the Prophet () offer a cow as a sacrifice? (See for example sahih [al-Bukhari](https://sunnah.com/bukhari:5559) and sahih [Muslim](https://sunnah.com/muslim:1211i)).
This is by far not the only contradiction to this hadith showing that the Prophet() ate cow meat (see for example in sahih [al-Bukhari](https://sunnah.com/bukhari:3089) and sahih [Muslim](https://sunnah.com/muslim:715t) when he came close to Medina during his hijra, again in sahih al-[Bukhari](https://sunnah.com/bukhari:2577) and sahih [Muslim](https://sunnah.com/muslim:1075a) where he accepted it as sadaqa)

There are many so called explanations of this hadith:
I think @Casanova pointed at almost all of them.

I'd like to add an other one which is quoted in [this fatwa in Arabic](https://www.islamweb.net/ar/fatwa/76185):
This Prohibition for cow meat is not general, but rather special, as for example the hijaz is a very dry area and therefore the meat of cows there is also rather dry which made this meat causing sickness or harm to the people of hijaz.

However sheik al-'Othaymen seems to hold a very different opinion:
When asked how to solve the contradiction which comes due to the different qualifications of this hadith, earlier scholars have mostly considered it as da'if, while later scholars have qualified it as sahih?
<sup>In the following I'll be roughly translating from Arabic language, as these translations are of my own take them carefully.</sup>

> وسئل ابن عثيمين في حديث لحوم البقر الذي جاء في آخره: أن "لحمه داء".بعض العلماء المعاصرين صححه، فكيف الجمع بين تصحيحهم وبين تضعيف بعض علماء السلف؟
>
> الجواب: لا يحتاج هذا إلى جمع، أتظن أن ربك سبحانه وتعالى يبيح لك ما فيه ضررك؟ لا يمكن، إذا كان أباح لحم البقر بنص القرآن، كيف يقال: إن لحمها داء؟!! إذا كان الحديث الشاذ المخالف للأرجح منه في الرواية يرد، فالحديث المخالف للقرآن يجب رده.
> ([source](http://alkulify.blogspot.de/2013/11/blog-post_8231.html) where you might find other explanations of this hadith)

> He answered promptly: There's no reason to solve an issue, do you think your Creator would allow you something which might cause harm?
> That's impossible, if Allah has clearly allowed to eat the meat of cows by qur'an, how can we say it's meat causes sickness?
> If a hadith shadh is contradicting a stronger source, we must reject it, so a hadith contrddicting the qur'an has to be rejected!

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I read a similar fatwa about the prohibiton being just in Hijaz, i think it was ibn jawzi. But surely, the opinion of Al-Uthayman was surprising! was not aware of that

Comment: There are two aspects I wanted to comment, First you mentioned that "" Also note that if this hadith was sahih? Why did the Prophet () offer a cow as a sacrifice? "" Does the prophet sacrificing a cow entails that hadith is not sahih ? I don't think so because cow meat isn't haraam but Nabi SAW only gives a hint about eating it when other alternatives are available. Today, modern science has proved that bovine meat is a great source of disease. And the Nabi SAW sacrificed a cow for his wives, that he had many, so a big animal was needed else he would have most probably stick to another one.

Comment: Also, you mention ""This is by far not the only contradiction to this hadith showing that the Prophet() ate cow meat "", the same comment, He doing it doesn't contradict the truthfulness of the statement

Comment: @Noor a hadith contradicting the qur'an can't be regarded as truthful, else it is doubtful whether one can still be regarded as a Muslim! And the subject or explanation of the contradiction of this hadith -if it was taken as truthful-, is that too much consumption of meat is unhealthy. Only then it can be regarded as acceptable. Note that Allah allowed us a lot of things and made them permissible, but Allah also showed us that excess in anything is not good.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, eating beef is permissible in Islam.

Even though many Muslims brothers have answered this question, I would like to point out one narration from Umar bin Khataab (May Allah Be Pleased With Him) that indicates that meat should be consumed in a moderate way.

Scholars like Al-bani who have authenticated the Hadith have said that the prohibition is referring to **excessive consumption of meat only.**

The following narration from Umar Bin Al-Khataab clarifies this issue:-

**Al-Muwaṭṭa’ 1742 states:-**

**Yahya ibn Sa’id reported: Umar ibn al-Khattab, may Allah be pleased with him, said, “Beware of meat, for meat can be as addictive as wine.”**