# Why is caffeine and coffee considered halal?

Tags: halal-haram, food

As with smoking, there are a number of negative side effects when consuming caffeine, especially in high quantities. Insomnia, nervousness, restlessness, irritability, an upset stomach, a fast heartbeat and even muscle tremors may occur. Besides that it can be quite addictive. In many respects it seems quite akin to smoking.

Yet, as far as I can tell, there have been no rulings on caffeine or caffeinated beverages. Is it simply that scholars have not investigated it yet?

Comment: "In many respects it seems quite akin to smoking" Well, apart from the cancer.

Comment: If I remember right, there is an ongoing debate among the scholars (not islamic) about for instance coffee, if its healthy or not. And if I am updated, the leading opinion is that it rather is healthy. Regarding high quantities, that would be an exception of the general rule that it is allowed, if it could lead to damage. This is true about everything, even food, see [this](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/39678/15201) which is related

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically because caffeine is not classed as an intoxicant.

[SeekersHub](http://seekershub.org/ans-blog/2011/07/13/why-is-caffeine-not-haram/) explains this as:

> So what is meant by intoxicant in this context is that which “covers the intellect,” i.e., causes inebriation or drunkenness like beer, or euphoria such as cocaine or amphetamines. These are all unlawful. ... **Caffeine is not an intoxicant in that sense, but rather only a mild stimulant and hence permissible.**

quoting the hadith

> ... [Khamr] is that which clouds the intellect ... -- Sahih Muslim 3032 a ([sunnah.com](https://sunnah.com/muslim/56/36))

This is consistent with fatawa by Islam Q&A ([1](https://islamqa.info/en/9237); [2](https://islamqa.info/en/118268)), [IslamWeb](http://www.islamweb.net/emainpage/index.php?page=showfatwa&Option=FatwaId&Id=84417), and [IslamToday](http://en.islamtoday.net/node/1088).

---

A [BBC article](http://www.historyextra.com/article/bbc-history-magazine/brief-history-coffee-drink-devil) discusses this history of a fatwa declaring coffee haram:

> Coffee drinking was banned by jurists and scholars meeting in Mecca in 1511. The opposition was led by the Meccan governor Khair Beg, who was afraid that coffee would foster opposition to his rule by bringing men together and allowing them to discuss his failings. Thus was born coffee’s association with sedition and revolution. It was decreed sinful (haraam), but the controversy over whether it was intoxicating or not raged on over the next 13 years until the ban was finally rescinded in 1524 by an order of the Ottoman Turkish Sultan Selim I, with Grand Mufti Mehmet Ebussuud el-İmadi issuing a fatwa allowing coffee to be drunk again. Beg was executed for his troubles by command of the Sultan himself, who further proclaimed coffee to be sacred. In Cairo there was a similar ban in 1532; coffee houses and coffee warehouses there were ransacked.

Answer (score 0):

Asalamu Aleykum Ikhwa. This Topic might be an Older Question but Daniel, you seem to got something wrong. Smoking isn't Haram because it counts as Intoxicant, it is Haram because, as proven by many sources, it is Harmful to your Body. I dont have all the Islamic sources at Hand, but it is in the Quran, and I have this Hadeeth:

‘Ubadah ibn al-Samit reported: The Messenger of Allah, peace and blessings be upon him, issued a decree, “Do not cause harm or return harm.” ~Sunan Ibn Mājah 2340

Your Body was given to you by Allah, and he still owns you, and it would be pretty bad if you damage it on Purpose which smoking does. Love Allah, but Also fear him Akhi. Fear his Punishment. 
Asalamu Aleykum

Answer (score -1):

***Dear Brother,***

Coffee is halal because it does not have any intoxicant.

All praise to the most high

Answer (score -2):

coffee is haram as basic statement; all is haram IF intention to intoxicate - if someone puts alcohol in your fruit juice WITHOUT you knowing; and then you drink it - then that alcoholic beverage is halal

BUT you are talking "disciple" level islam - more generally; it is "ok" to have a cup of coffee to "intoxicate yourself with motivation" IF you do good with your day ? (i.e. are a scholar and have to answer peoples really annoying questions all the time ? (- then i believe "yes" this is ok, but not halal as drinking water.)